# How to avoid the Reactjs (Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.). from below component

Tags: reactjs

```
export function UsePageVisibility() {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = React.useState(getIsDocumentHidden());
   
    console.log(isVisible);

    const onVisibilityChange = () => setIsVisible(getIsDocumentHidden());
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const visibilityChange = getBrowserVisibilityProp();
        window.addEventListener(visibilityChange, onVisibilityChange, false);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener(visibilityChange, onVisibilityChange);
        };
    }, []);

    return isVisible;
}
```

**Test.js**:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Component from "./component";

export function getBrowserVisibilityProp() {
    if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
        // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support
        return "visibilitychange";
    } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
        return "msvisibilitychange";
    } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
        return "webkitvisibilitychange";
    }
}
export function getBrowserDocumentHiddenProp() {
    if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
        return "hidden";
    } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
        return "msHidden";
    } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
        return "webkitHidden";
    }
}
export function getIsDocumentHidden() {
    return !document[getBrowserDocumentHiddenProp()];
}

export function UsePageVisibility() {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = React.useState(getIsDocumentHidden());
   const [counter , setcounter] = useState(false);
    console.log(isVisible);

    const onVisibilityChange = () => setIsVisible(getIsDocumentHidden());
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const visibilityChange = getBrowserVisibilityProp();
        window.addEventListener(visibilityChange, onVisibilityChange, false);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener(visibilityChange, onVisibilityChange);
        };
    }, []);


    if (!isVisible) {
        setcounter(true);
    } else {
        setcounter(false);
    }
    return isVisible;

}
```

**App.js**:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { UsePageVisibility } from "./test";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <UsePageVisibility />;
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I have been searching and trying all possible solutions but nothing helps..

Comment: this component return true if u r in the same tab of browser and false if u r in some other tab

Comment: I want to catch the user as soon as he goes to another tab and display a permanent message after he comes to the page again

Comment: "this component return true if u r in the same tab of browser and false if u r in some other tab" Is this how it *actually* functions, or is that how you *want* it to function? I see nothing overt here to cause render looping. How and where is this custom hook being used? What is the component that is render looping?

Comment: this is a component which is being imported in App.js. Yes, it returns true or false on basis of if u are in the same tab or not. The problem is that I am not able to set the state in this component

Comment: That is a react hook, not a react component. We need to see the component using it to see why you aren't seeing the behavior you expect. Perhaps it is another component causing looping, we don't know though since you've not shared any component code.

Answer (score 1):

This error could occur when you have a function calling itself once the component mounts.

Try:

```
const onVisibilityChange = () => setIsVisible(() => getIsDocumentHidden());
```